# ios 7 unstable animation issue when deleting a row in a table view

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

I have a table view with a search bar/display controller (all built in story board).
My problem is with deleting rows. The functionality of delete row works BUT the animation of row deletion seems to be unstable. Sometimes the deletion is animated and most of the times the row is removed immediately with no animation.

This is my delete method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:[_notesFilteredFetcher objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        } else {
            [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:[_notesFetcher objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        }
        NSError *error;
        if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            DLog(@"Failed deleting note : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

The table view is using core data so the deletion of the rows occur in the appropriate controller's method as follows:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = (controller == _notesFilteredFetcher) ? self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView : self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath forTable:tableView];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

I also noticed that when animation for delete does occur, all rows above the deleted row move a bit down and the rows under the deleted row move up until the empty space is covered.

If I look at the built-in **mail** app and delete some rows (i.e. mails) it does seem to animate as expected every time and ONLY the rows below the deleted row are moved up to cover the empty space (the rows above the deleted row do not move).

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE:**

I have noticed that animation does occur only for the last row. If I delete any other row  no animation occurs but if I delete the last row animation does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone bumps into the same problem :

I noticed that I called `reloadData` method of the table view right after the call to `endUpdates` of the same table view as I needed to update the cell's internal indices.

This will cause the animation to stop immediately. Removing the `reloadData` method solved the animation issue.